# Is there a way to turn a pull request back into a draft pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I started using the new draft pull request feature on Github, but I'm wondering if I can turn a legit pull request back into a draft pull request in the case I accidentally make a pull request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated [on Twitter from the GitHub Support](https://twitter.com/GitHubHelp/status/1097580505422278658), there is currently no way to do so.

> There is not currently a way to convert an existing pull request into a draft. Thanks for the suggestion! I've passed it on to the appropriate team. Thanks!

---

**Update:**

It is now possible to turn a pull request into a draft pull request. You can read about it in the [Github Help Documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/changing-the-stage-of-a-pull-request#converting-a-pull-request-to-a-draft).